# Rebalancing a Cassandra Ring with Vnodes

Tags: performance, cassandra, load, cassandra-2.0

We had a system with a 3-node Cassandra 2.0.6 ring. Over time, the application load on that system increased until a limit where the ring could not handle it anymore, causing the typical node overload failures.

We doubled the size of the ring, and recently even added one more node, to try to handle the load, but there're still only 3 nodes taking all the load; but not the original 3 nodes of the initial ring.

We did the `bootstrap` + `cleanup` process described in the [adding nodes guide](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html). We also tried `repairs` on each node after not seeing much improvements in the ring load. Our load is 99.99% writes on this system.

Here's a chart of the cluster load illustrating the issue:

[image]

The highest load tables have a high cardinality on the partition key that I'd expect distributes well over vnodes.

Edit: nodetool info

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  x.y.z.92     56.83 GB   256     13.8%  x-y-z-b53e8ab55e0a  rack1
UN  x.y.z.253    136.87 GB  256     15.2%  x-y-z-bd3cf08449c8  rack1
UN  x.y.z.70     69.84 GB   256     14.2%  x-y-z-39e63dd017cd  rack1
UN  x.y.z.251    74.03 GB   256     14.4%  x-y-z-36a6c8e4a8e8  rack1
UN  x.y.z.240    51.77 GB   256     13.0%  x-y-z-ea239f65794d  rack1
UN  x.y.z.189    128.49 GB  256     14.3%  x-y-z-7c36c93e0022  rack1
UN  x.y.z.99     53.65 GB   256     15.2%  x-y-z-746477dc5db9  rack1
```

Edit: tpstats  (node highly loaded)

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
ReadStage                         0         0       11591287         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0      283211224         0                 0
MutationStage                    32    405875      349531549         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0           3591         0                 0
ReplicateOnWriteStage             0         0              0         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0        3246983         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0          72055         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0            133         0                 0
MemoryMeter                       0         0            205         0                 0
MemtablePostFlusher               0         0          94915         0                 0
FlushWriter                       0         0          12521         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0          34680         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0             14         0                 0
commitlog_archiver                0         0              0         0                 0
AntiEntropySessions               1         1              1         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0             30         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     0         0           1957         0                 0

Message type           Dropped
RANGE_SLICE                  0
READ_REPAIR                196
PAGED_RANGE                  0
BINARY                       0
READ                         0
MUTATION              31663792
_TRACE                   24409
REQUEST_RESPONSE             4
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
```

How could I further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Can you add the output of `nodetool status` and `nodetool netstats`?

Comment: @StefanPodkowinski added `nodetool info`. `nodetool netstats` might not be accurate at the moment as we're executing some actions on the ring.

Comment: @maasg, Looking at the output of nodetool info looks like the load is pretty evenly distributed. But seems likes the previous data was not deleted in some nodes. Was cleanup run on these nodes ?

Comment: @DesertIce `cleanup` _should have_ run on the original nodes. The load on the cluster is 99.99% writes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run nodetool cleanup on the previous nodes that were part of the ring. Nodetool cleanup will remove the partition keys that the node currently does not own.

Seems like after the addition of the nodes, the keys have not been deleted hence causing the load to be higher on the previous nodes.

Try running

```
nodetool cleanup

     on the previous nodes
```

Comment: would that affect writes?

Comment: @maasg, It should effect the disk load on the previous machines. When you say the cluster write load is 99.9% writes, what does that actually mean. How are you defining that?

Comment: Write load for that system is about 500-1000 msgs/sec - The writes are mostly new columns on existing keys, never overwrites. Our read are occasional, based on aggregated reports. 99.99% is an 'educated guess'. We have a 2nd system of similar size and Cassandra runs at a smooth 10% CPU across 6 nodes.

Comment: So you are defining write load as the number of messages? Wouldn't it make sense to define it based on CPU or disk load?

Comment: @maasg, can you paste the output of nodetool tpstats?

Comment: thanks for the interest. I added the tpstats output of a "hot" server.

Comment: @Seems like your nodes have a lot of pending writes/updates. This can be caused by a wide variety of causes like disk errors or improper data modeling. Any chance your data modeling is causing hotspots?